# Запуск скрипта в зависимости от доменого имени

Tags: javascript, php, django, битрикс

Переводим сервер на новый домен, сейчас сайт доступен по двум разным адресам. Хочу вывести окно с информацией о скором прекращении работы старого домена. Есть ли возможность выводить данное окно только тем пользователям которые зашли на сайт по старому адресу? Этот сайт на Битрикс, но в последствии хочется перевести ещё сайты на django. Возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: Анализируйте заголовки пришедшего запроса https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host

Comment: Я понял что заголовки можно отследить, а вот потом то как с ними работать? Что то типа `if(Host: www.site.ru == true) { выполнение чего ни будь }`  Как то так?

Comment: да, как-то так. условие в шаблоне для вывода текста